# Are there any Guice JMS integrations

Tags: jms, guice

I'd like to integrate our Guice application with JMS. We are using ActiveMQ but any generic JMS module should be fine. I'm looking for something that is maintained and similar to Spring's JMSTemplate that works nicely with Guice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on exactly the same problematic with similar context.

I found this : https://github.com/aqingsao/i1-guice-jms which comes from an older google code project. 
Perhaps, could be a nice bootstrap for your needs.

Comment: How did it work out for you? I ended up using apache camel, which works nicely but is not very light weight and ends up pulling in certain spring jars with it